# how to generate an array of number in a skewed normal distribution?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generating random numbers from skewed normal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395012/generating-random-numbers-from-skewed-normal-distribution)

i expect a long array containing integers
[3,7,7,7,7,1....]

but the overall distribution  should be skewed and normal.

using random() generates a uniform distribution.....

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't get exactly what you are asking.

Comment: What is even being asked here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for just a few integers as your random numbers, then divide the range of random numbers accordingly.

For example, if your random function returns a number from zero to 1, and you want "3" to have a frequency of 10%, and "7" a frequency of 40%, you could say something like

uneven_rand()
{

  r = rand();
  if (r < 0.1) return 3; // covers range from 0 to 0.1
  if (r < 0.5) return 7; // Covers range from 0.1 to 0.5
  etc...

}